# (0.7/0.001)%10 is not returning 0

Tags: php, bitcoin

I am creating a bitcoin based ad platform for a bitcoin learning portal. The reason I mention it is, I believe, it'll help to understand my problem and thereby I may get a better solution. What am I doing is simply passing the amount an user will pay from an HTML form to a PHP page and checking whether it is a multiple of 10. The code snippet is as follows...

```
$orderAmount = $_POST['orderAmount'];
$adUnitPrice = 0.001;
if((($orderAmount/$adUnitPrice) % 10) == 0)
    $standardPayment = true;
else
    $standardPayment = false;
```

When I am passing $orderAmount as 0.6 or 0.8, I get the expected return of $standardPayment = true. But, when I am passing $orderAmount as 0.7, I get the unexpected return of $standardPayment = false !!! Can someone please tell me what is the problem and how to fix this ?

Comment: I normally get around decimal precision problems by representing money values as integers instead of floats.

Comment: are you try the [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/es/book.bc.php) module. `bcdiv("0.7", "0.001")` returns `700`

Comment: @rkmax Did not understand what you are saying...

Comment: @Drahcir 1 Bitcoin === 100,000,000 satoshi, the latter being the smallest divisible unit of a bitcoin.  Numbers like that make using integer math harder than it would be for cents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[bcmath](http://php.net/manual/es/book.bc.php) module  can help you

```
bcmod(bcdiv("0.7", "0.001"), "10"); // returns 0
```

in your code

```
$orderAmount = $_POST['orderAmount'];
$adUnitPrice = 0.001;
if(bcmod(bcdiv($orderAmount, $adUnitPrice), 10) == 0) {
    $standardPayment = true;
} else {
    $standardPayment = false;
}
```

or even

```
$standardPayment = (bcmod(bcdiv($orderAmount, $adUnitPrice), 10) == 0);
```

you can check on command line with `php -m` and look if has the module or write a file with the follow

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and look if has enable the module **bcmath**

Answer (score 2):

Neither 0.7 or 0.001 are *exactly* representable in IEEE 754 floating point math - see numerous other related questions here.

Hence when you divide 0.7 by 0.001 you do not get exactly 700, but something very close to 700 instead (probably 699.99999999999988631316)  and therefore the modulus test fails.

You should round your price to the nearest cent (or 10th of a cent, or similar) and then perform your "standard payment" test.

Comment: But, that should happen for 0.6 and 0.8 as well. This problem is not occurring even if I pass 0.07 !!!

Comment: @MidnightEngineer  For 0.6 and 0.8 it appears that the errors cancel out leaving you with a valid integer.

Comment: that depends on exactly how close to 10 bucks you want it.  Below a 10th of a cent or so it probably doesn't matter.